# Привязка данных TreeView к RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, richtextbox

Я тут создаю диалоговый редактор для игры и у меня появилась проблема, которую я никак не могу решить. Как можно реализовать подобную вещь:

1. Есть два вместе находящихся элемента на форме RichTextBox и один TreeView.
2. В TreeView с помощью кнопки добавляются узлы.
3. При нажатии на узел активируется первый RichTextBox, при нажати на его подузел второй RichTextBox.
4. В данный RichTextBox можно что-то вписать и это сохраниться в выбранном узле/подузле (не в двух сразу).
5. Если юзер нажмет на другой узел или их подузел, то RichTextBox очистится, но при повторном нажатии на тот прошлый узел те, ранее вписанные данные, вновь появятся в RichTextBox.
6. И так можно привязывать данные к любому выбранному узлу.
7. Данные каждого узла я смогу получить через код в будущем.

Меня больше всего интересует **4,5,6 и 7** пункт. Остальное я уже реализовал, а вот с этими я даже не представляю как. Я знаю про существование Tag у узлов, но это не дает мне никакого представления реализации подобного. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Слишком высокий уровень абстрактности вашего вопроса. Можете его конкретизировать? Например добавьте в вопрос код и скриншот, схему алгоритма, что-нибудь, что позволит понять, как же оно у вас работает. Можете создать новый тестовый проект, в котором попытаться реализовать то, что у вас не получается, а потом добавить сюда нерабочий код из этого тестового проекта.

Comment: Создайте класс для данных, с свойствами, которые хранят название ноды для дерева и текст для `RichTextBox`, переопределите у класса `ToString()`, поддержите древовидную структуру, добавив в класс свойство того же типа, чтои сам класс. При создании ноды `TreeView` одновременно создавайте ноду в дереве свойих данных, то есть храните копию того что на экране. При создании ноды прикрепляйте не строку к ее названию, а экземпляр своего класса. В обработчике события выбора ноды вы сразу сможете получить все необходимые данные для обновления текстбоксов. Это не просто в Winforms, но возможно.

Comment: Сложность реализации подобных штук в Winforms была побеждена моей ленью писать по 500 строк кода для каждой простой задачи, и я ушел в WPF+MVVM. Там интерактивная привязка данных - нативная фича, для использования которой вполне хватает одной прямой извилины моего мозга. :)

Comment: @aepot на самом деле никаких 500+ строк не требуется да же в древних формах, единственный известная мне проблема - заполнение дефолтного treeview, это надо делать руками, остальное точно также решается биндингами. Документации с примерами по ним не так много как для WPF, но при желании найти можно. Тогда написание формы и всего интерактива на ней сводится к передаче источника данных в форму и создания связыванию свойств источника со свойствами контролов.

Comment: @rdorn может вы и правы, но я сужу по своему прошлому опыту мучений в Winforms и сравниваю с тем, что я теперь могу с легкостью вытворять в WPF. :) 2 большие разницы. В Winforms я не встречал нерешаемых задач, но там более низкоуровневый подход к реализации, и то что ты получаешь в WPF "из коробки" - там надо либо подключать из внешних библиотек, либо писать самому. А еще в Winforms война со всякими полупрозрачностями и прочими проблемами при наведении красоты, которая опять же отсутствует в WPF. :) Ладно, пофлудили и хватит. Автору по-прежнему рекомендуется добавить конкретики в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем-то ваша задача решается довольно просто если разделить данные и их отображение. Поэтому для начала сделаем простую модель данных для демонстрации (под свои данные адаптируете самостоятельно):

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubItemModel> SubItems { get; } = new List<SubItemModel>();
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class SubItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ItemModel Parent { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

//Обращаю внимание на необходимость реализации INotifyPropertyChanged
//для правильной работы биндингов
public class TreeModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //выбранные значения заполняем пустышками
    private ItemModel _selectedItem = new ItemModel();
    private SubItemModel _selectedSubItem = new SubItemModel();

    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; } = new List<ItemModel>();

    public ItemModel SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItem)));
        }
    }

    public SubItemModel SelectedSubItem
    {
        get => _selectedSubItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedSubItem = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedSubItem)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //Для примера заполним модель данными в конструкторе, но разумеется это нужно
    //делать в более подходящем месте вашей программы
    public TreeModel()
    {
        var item = new ItemModel { Name = "Item1", Text = "Item1 Text" };
        item.SubItems.Add(new SubItemModel { 
            Name = "SubItem11", Text = "SubItem11 Text", Parent = item });
        item.SubItems.Add(new SubItemModel { 
            Name = "SubItem12", Text = "SubItem12 Text", Parent = item });
        Items.Add(item);
        item = new ItemModel { Name = "Item2", Text = "Item2 Text" };
        item.SubItems.Add(new SubItemModel { 
            Name = "SubItem21", Text = "SubItem21 Text", Parent = item });
        item.SubItems.Add(new SubItemModel { 
            Name = "SubItem22", Text = "SubItem22 Text", Parent = item });
        Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Подготовительные работы закончены, теперь немного непривычной магии в коде формы:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly TreeModel Model = new TreeModel();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillVisualTree(treeView1.Nodes);
        treeView1.AfterSelect += TreeView1_AfterSelect;
        //добавляем двусторонние привязки к модели с возможностью обновления данных
        richTextBox1.DataBindings.Add(
            new Binding("Text", Model, "SelectedItem.Text", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, ""));
        richTextBox2.DataBindings.Add(
            new Binding("Text", Model, "SelectedSubItem.Text", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, ""));
    }

    private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Node.Tag)
        {
            case ItemModel i:
                Model.SelectedItem = i;
                //когда выбран корневой элемент подставляем пустышку в дочерний
                Model.SelectedSubItem = new SubItemModel();
                break;
            case SubItemModel si:
                Model.SelectedSubItem = si;
                Model.SelectedItem = si.Parent;
                break;
        }
    }

    //Вспомогательный метод для заполнения TreView
    private void FillVisualTree(TreeNodeCollection tree)
    {
        foreach (var i in Model.Items)
        {
            var node = new TreeNode { Text = i.Name, Tag = i };
            foreach (var si in i.SubItems)
            {
                var subnode = new TreeNode { Text = si.Name, Tag = si };
                node.Nodes.Add(subnode);
            }
            tree.Add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Код дизайнера с добавлением элементов формы остался за кадром и не представляет интереса.

Comment: Полезный пример, спасибо.

Comment: @Bulson, не удержался, просто надоело смотреть на жалобы что в формах все сложно. Красоту наводить - сложно, это проблема самой технологии отображения в принципе, а в остальном вся сложность в необходимости изучить возможности и научиться их применять.

Comment: WinForms в этом смысле малость не повезло. Свежих книг по данной технологии не пишут. Нормальных курсов тоже нет, а то что есть повсеместно учат писать `textBox.Text = "Hello Word!"` а привязкам совсем не обучают.

Comment: @rdorn С текстом понятно, а как быть с комбобоксами? Т.е.  сохранить выбранный выбранный элемент в комбобоксе для узла.

Comment: @Alex по тому же принципу, все что нужно сохранить - сохраняем в модели и привязываем биндингами в контролах. SelectedItem в комбобоксе также биндится. Вообще все свойства контролов биндятся при необходимости и желании. Попробуйте самостоятельно, если не получится, задайте еще один вопрос, только покажите в вопросе как именно пробовали.

Comment: @Alex такой подход (с биндингами) несколько сложнее в плане требований к проработке модели, но сильно упрощает код самих форм и дальнейшее его сопровождение и модификацию. Просто относитесь к контролам как к способу показать что-то, что у вас уже существует вне контролов, так же как в веб-приложениях например.

Comment: @rdorn Еще один небольшой вопрос. Вот есть FillVisualAnswer, проблема в том, что он добавляет все элементы разом. У меня же все работает иначе. Есть отдельная кнопка для добавления главного узла и отдельная для подузла. Первая кнопка создает основные узлы, а вторая в зависимости от выбранного основного узла создает его подузлы. Я попробовал разделить FillVisualThree, он успешно создает главные узлы, но подузлы создаются только для последнего созданного главного узла. Мне нужно чтобы этой кнопкой создавались подузлы только для выбранных узлов. Могу создать отдельный вопрос с кодом.

Comment: @Alex разумеется можете, нет смысла валить все в кучу в одном вопросе. Можно разделить, я уже подумал, что вам это понадобится, но не стал торопить события. У TreeView, к сожалению, самая плохая реализация в этом аспекте, но все возможно.

Comment: @rdorn Написал вопрос. Немного перебощил с информацией, но это только от неумения кратко и понятно объяснять.

Comment: @rdorn Я попробовал забиндить комбобокс такой строкой `ChangeTone_DropList.DataBindings.Add(
                new Binding("SelectedItem", Model, "SelectedSubItem.ItemBoxTone", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, ""));` Но что-то компилятор мне выдает исключение при попытке нажать на главный узел  "Невозможно преобразовать объект типа "System.DBNull" к типу "System.String"." над строкой `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedSubItem)));` в SelectedSubItem

Comment: @Alex а как у вас заполняется `ComboBox`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107827/discussion-between-rdorn-and-alex).