# Как можно правильно разделить представленный метод на две отдельные кнопки?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

В общем-то, еще один вопрос по Формам от меня ([предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1122613/198316)). Есть две LinkLabel кнопки и один TreeView. Первая кнопка добавляет основной узел, вторая подузел для выбранного узла. У самого же TreeView данные и отображение разделены, соответственно есть своя отдельная модель данных, а с ней метод **FillVisualTree** который вносит узлы с данными в сам список TreeView:

```
    public void FillVisualTree(TreeNodeCollection tree)
    {
        foreach (var i in Items)
        {
            var node = new TreeNode { Text = i.Name, Tag = i };
            foreach (var si in i.SubItems)
            {
                var subnode = new TreeNode { Text = si.Name, Tag = si };
                node.Nodes.Add(subnode);
            }
            tree.Add(node);
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что этот метод заносит все узлы/подузлы разом, а у меня две отдельные кнопки, как выше уже писал, первая для добавления главного узла и вторая для добавления подузла к выбранному узлу.

Я попробовал разделить этот метод, чтобы он добавлял узлы по кускам.

Cначала занес в поля класса экземпляр класса "дерева", дабы иметь доступ вне метода:

```
private TreeNode node;
```

Далее создал метод **FillVisualTreeRoot** для добавления основного узла:

```
        public void FillVisualTreeRoot(TreeNodeCollection tree)
        {
         node = new TreeNode();
         foreach (var i in Items)
         {
            node.Text = i.Name;
            node.Tag = i;
         }
        tree.Add(node);
        }
```

И **FillVisualTreeAnswer** для его подузла:

```
        public void FillVisualTreeAnswer(TreeNodeCollection tree)
        {
        var subnode = new TreeNode();
        foreach (var i in Items)
        {
            foreach (var si in i.SubItems)
            {
                subnode.Text = si.Name;
                subnode.Tag = si;               
            }
        }
        node.Nodes.Add(subnode);
       }
```

Также внес в поля уже класса Формы экземпляр модели данных:

```
ItemModel item;
```

Потом в обработчике события кнопки для создания узла внес все данные и вызвал ранее созданный метод **FillVisualTreeRoot**, который должен добавлять узлы с данными в список:

```
      private void NewRoot_Label_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
      {
            item = new ItemModel { Name = "Item1", Text = "Item1 Text" };
            Model.Items.Add(item);
            Model.FillVisualTreeRoot(Roots_TreeView.Nodes);
      }
```

Все работает на отлично

[image: И он действительно выполняет работу на отлично]

Но у меня еще не задействована кнопка добавления подузлов.

В обработчике события второй кнопки для подузлов я также внес данные и вызвал второй метод **FillVisualTreeAnswer** и казалось бы все отлично, но он работает совсем иначе. Место того чтобы добавлять подузлы к ВЫБРАННЫМ узлам, он делает это только с последними созданными:

[image: Как видите у меня выбран пятый узел, а подузлы добавлены только к последним]

Немного подумав, я все таки догадываюсь в чем проблема, в общем экземпляре **TreeNode nodе**, который используется в двух методах в качестве добавления узлов в список. 
Так вот, как можно ПРАВИЛЬНО разделить метод **FillVisualTree** на две кнопки чтобы он ПРАВИЛЬНО создавал и разделял узлы/подузлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вы зря привязали добавление визуального элемента дерева к модели, хотя в этом, отчасти, моя вина, поправил предыдущий ответ.

Так как за отображение отвечает форма, то интерактивное добавление визуальных элементов следует оставить именно ей. Модифицируйте обработчики кликов по ссылке следующим образом:

```
private void NewRoot_Label_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = new ItemModel { Name = "Item1", Text = "Item1 Text" };
    Model.Items.Add(item);
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Text = item.Name, Tag = item });
}

private void AddChild_Label_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    //эта проверка нужна, чтобы дочерние узлы добавлялись только в выбранный корень
    //и не добавлялись в дочерние
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode?.Tag is ItemModel item)
    {
        var subItem = new SubItemModel { Name = "Item1", Text = "Item1 Text", Parent = item };
        item.SubItems.Add(subItem);
        treeView1.SelectedNode?.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Text = subItem.Name, Tag = subItem });
        //ну и сразу развернем узел в который добавили элемент
        treeView1.SelectedNode?.Expand();
    }
}
```

К большому сожалению, реализация штатного `TreeView` в WinForms довольно "топорная" и не поддерживает автоматическую привязку данных через свойство `DataSource`, которое у него просто отсутствует в отличие от, например, `ListBox` или `ComboBox`. Поэтому добавление, удаление и начальную генерацию узлов данного контрола приходится делать руками.

Также стоит посмотреть в сторону классов `BindingList<T>` и `BindingSource`.

Есть неплохая [статья по основам привязки данных](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/Data_Binding_Basics.xml), только читать надо очень внимательно, при беглом просмотре можно упустить важные детали.